# p:selectOneMenu, custom content and editable=true

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have the following usage of the `p:selectOneMenu`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectField"
    value="#{someBean.someField}"
    converter="#{selectItemConverter}" var="x" editable="true">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{selectItemsBean.getSelectItems(tab, field)}" var="si"
        itemLabel="#{si.label}" itemValue="#{si}" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{si.label}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="noway_16x16.png"
            title="#{si.disabledReason}" rendered="#{si.disabled}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" partialSubmit="true" process="selectField" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

As you can see, I use custom content in combination with `editable=true`. When I submit the form, the Converter gets the label of a selected item as the value, not the actual value. In the HTML page, the values are correct, e.g. `<option value="C">C-style mounting</option>`. With `editable=false`, the correct value (e.g. `C` is sent to the converter, with `editable=true` the converter retrieves `C-style mounting`.

What I want is that the user can either select one of the pre-defined items in the list and the server submits that value of the item *OR* the user enters something and that is submitted as value. But the current behavior is a bit strange - or am I just wanting too much?

Comment: After a lot more searching I found this thread on the Primefaces forum, basically discussing the same issue: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19638 Short version: No can do, having both, a Pojo-based SelectOneMenu and an editable one.